# Maven: How can I run/include a class in a jar with the failsafe plugin?

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-failsafe-plugin

I've made my own class with an `@RunWith(AllTests.class)` on it for integration tests that I want to execute, but I've put it in a reusable jar.  I'm trying to tell failsafe to use it but I'm not sure how to because [the documentation for includes](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) says:

> A list of  elements specifying the tests (by pattern) that should be included in testing. When not specified and when the test parameter is not specified, the default includes will be
>
> ```
> <includes>
>  <include>**/IT*.java</include>
>  <include>**/*IT.java</include>
>  <include>**/*ITCase.java</include>
> </includes>
> ```
>
> Each include item may also contain a comma-separated sublist of items, which will be treated as multiple   entries.
>       This parameter is ignored if the TestNG suiteXmlFiles parameter is specified.

But this test runner is in the classpath, not on the filesystem.  How can I tell failsafe to use my class runner and only my class runner?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*test runner*. If you mean an instance of [Runner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/Runner.html) you'll need to add the the jar in the dependency section with the `scope=test`

Comment: @Augusto Which dependency section?  Of the plugin?  It's not an instance of `Runner`, it's a Pojo with the `@RunWith(AllTests.class)` annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use the [@RunWith](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html) annotation provided by jUnit?

```
import com.example.YourTestRunner;

@RunWith(YourTestRunner.class)
public class SomeIntegrationTest {

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
       // given, when, then
    }
}
```

**Update**

Based on the comment:

> My class isn't a test runner, but a class that uses @RunWith

you can use inheritance to solve the problem:

```
@RunWith(SomeTestRunner.class)
@Ignore("Not a real test class because it does not contain any @Test methods, but needed to keep surefire happy")
public class ParentTest {
    // this is the reusable class that is in the jar file
}


public class SomeIntegrationTest extends ParentTest {

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
       // given, when, then
    }
}
```

Comment: I have mispoken.  My class isn't a test runner, but a class that uses `@RunWith`.

Comment: This is not working for me but it's very difficult to figure out why.  `-X` gives me 100x more info than I need so I can't figure out why it's not finding this `SomeIntegrationTest`.

Comment: I guess that you already verified that you have added the jar as a dependency. Next, you have to make sure that the class that you are extending is located in a subfolder of the `src/main/java` folder (and not the `src/test/java`, since any class in this folder will be used for test only, and not packaged in the jar).